# Gmail-API with python

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

i'm building python GMAIL API for checking emails for 10 email accounts
but in google documentation not very useful.
this seems only support one account
https://github.com/suleenwong/Gmail-API-Python

Answer (score 1):

If we check the default sample [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) This sample was designed to be single user but that can be changed.

The following section creates a token.json file when the user authorizes the application.  The file will contain the access token and refresh token for the user who authorized the code.

If the file does not exist then the app will prompt the user to authorize it. If it does then the app will load the credentials from that file and run the code with the authorization of that user.

```
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
```

To add more users you can simply rename that file tokenUserOne.json, tokenUserTwo.json.  Then set it up so that you can supply the file name you want your script to run on.  You will only need to authorize each user once. As long as you have a token.json file for each user separated, your app can then be started using which ever token file you want, to access each users data.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python -this is the proper documentation everything you need is in here

aka (you also need a client_secet.json file but you will have to get yourself for the google cloud dashbord):

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
        labels = results.get('labels', [])

        if not labels:
            print('No labels found.')
            return
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: yes i already done this but the real problem is i cant setup this for multiplie gmail accounts

Comment: I'm not sure this answer attempts to answer the question asked.   Please read [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Are you still in test mode?  Did you add the addresses into your Google portal?

Comment: yes still in test mode